# Numpy calculate gradients accross matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the following to calculate the running gradients between data in the same indexes across multiple matrices:

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
array_2 = np.array([[2,3,4], [5,6,7]])
array_3 = np.array([[1,8,9], [9,6,7]])

flat_1 = array_1.flatten()
flat_2 = array_2.flatten()
flat_3 = array_3.flatten()
print('flat_1: {0}'.format(flat_1))
print('flat_2: {0}'.format(flat_2))
print('flat_3: {0}'.format(flat_3))
data = []
gradient_list = []
for item in zip(flat_1,flat_2,flat_3):
    data.append(list(item))
    print('items: {0}'.format(list(item)))
    grads = np.gradient(list(item))
    print('grads: {0}'.format(grads))
    gradient_list.append(grads)

grad_array=np.array(gradient_list)
print('grad_array: {0}'.format(grad_array))
```

This doesn't look like an optimal way of doing this - is there a vectorized way of calculating gradients between data in 2d arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.gradient` takes `axis` as parameter, so you might just stack the arrays, and then calcualte the gradient along a certain axis; For instance, use `np.dstack` with `axis=2`; If you need a different shape as result, just use `reshape` method:

```
np.gradient(np.dstack((array_1, array_2, array_3)), axis=2)

#array([[[ 1. ,  0. , -1. ],
#        [ 1. ,  3. ,  5. ],
#        [ 1. ,  3. ,  5. ]],
#       [[ 1. ,  2.5,  4. ],
#        [ 1. ,  0.5,  0. ],
#        [ 1. ,  0.5,  0. ]]])
```

Or if flatten the arrays first:

```
np.gradient(np.column_stack((array_1.ravel(), array_2.ravel(), array_3.ravel())), axis=1)

#array([[ 1. ,  0. , -1. ],
#       [ 1. ,  3. ,  5. ],
#       [ 1. ,  3. ,  5. ],
#       [ 1. ,  2.5,  4. ],
#       [ 1. ,  0.5,  0. ],
#       [ 1. ,  0.5,  0. ]])
```